# AMF Channel without Livecycle, BlazeDS or similar

Tags: database, apache-flex, amf, amfphp, httpservice

Is it possible to use an AMF Channel in a Flex HTTPService client application without using Adobe Livecycle, BlazeDs or similar in order to do real time asynchronous request from an HTTPService?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an AMF HTTP call to any service that supports AMF.  There are many options, both free and commercial.

FluorineFx
http://www.fluorinefx.com/

AMF::Perl
http://www.simonf.com/flap/

WebORB
http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products

OpenAMF
http://sourceforge.net/projects/openamf/

AMFPHP
http://www.amfphp.org/

rubyamf
http://www.rubyamf.org/

PyAMF
http://pyamf.org/

Comment: Also Zend_Amf as an alternative to AMFPHP